# Using non-google webfonts via gscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, typography, google-slides

I am a Designer in a start-up and sadly most of our company uses the google suite to create documents, spreadsheets and slides. Of course we do not use a google font for our corporate design.

I am aware that you can only use Google Fonts typefaces in Google Docs, Slides etc.
Yet I was wondering if it would be possible to load a self-hosted webfont via the script editor and just override any font in a document.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Try Googling `load custom fonts for google docs`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at the time of this answer there is **no possible way of adding your custom fonts to Google Docs neither with the UI nor with a script**. That is because Docs use special web-based fonts (since it's a cloud-based app).

However, you can use and add aditional fonts by going to the document and then **Click on the font list-> More fonts**.

[Here](https://fonts.google.com/) you can see a list of the fonts available with further detail.

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)